# Sorting elements of a collection that has a hashMap Values elements - UnsupportedOperation Exception

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a sort method that sorts different types of collections. I tried sorting a Set, an `ArrayList`, a List and a collection of the values of a `HashMap`. All collections are correctly sorted except for the `hashMap.values()` collection which returns a UOE. I debugged the code and the problem is at line: "`numbers.add(a[k]);`" Do you have any idea on how can I make my sort method successfully sort the `hashMap.values()` collection? 
Here is the code:

```
public void sort(Collection<NamedValue> numbers)

{
    try
    {
        NamedValue[] a = numbers.toArray(new NamedValue[numbers.size()]) ; 
        boolean swapped = true;
        int j = 0;
        NamedValue temp;
        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length - j; i++) {
                if (a[i] != null && a[i].compareTo(a[i+1]) == 1)
                {
                    temp = a[i];
                    a[i] = a[i + 1];
                    a[i + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }   
        } 
        numbers.clear();
        for (int k=0; k<a.length; k++) {
            numbers.add(a[k]);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code from main :

```
    List<NamedValue> numbers = Arrays.asList(new NamedValue("One", 1), /**/
            new NamedValue("Three", 3), /**/
            new NamedValue("Four", 4), /**/
            new NamedValue("Two", 2), /**/
            new NamedValue("Five", 5));

    Map<String, NamedValue> numbersMap = new HashMap<String, NamedValue>();
    for (NamedValue value: numbers)
        numbersMap.put(value.Name(), value);
    System.out.println("numbersMap = " + numbersMap);

    Map<String, Collection<NamedValue>> collections = new HashMap<String, 
    Collection<NamedValue>>();
    collections.put("ArrayList", numbersArrayList);
    collections.put("List", numbersList);
    collections.put("Set", numbersSet);
    collections.put("Map values", numbersMap.values());

    for (String key: collections.keySet())
    {
        Collection<NamedValue> coll = collections.get(key);
        lab.sort(coll);
        System.out.println("Sorted " + key + " = " + coll);
    }
```

So I have a HashMap collections,and for each Collection from this map, I want to sort the elements. One of the collections consists of the values of the numbersMap collection. How can I make my sort method to sort all those collections( the hashMap.values() collection) ?

Comment: `AbstractCollection#add` is an optional method as described in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#add-E-). This means that not all collections have to support it. Apparently the collection produced by `HashMap#values` doesn't support it as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values--)

Comment: If you consider what you do here in case of a Map, it makes sense it fails. You take the values from a Map, sort the values, clear the whole map (removing all values **and** keys), and then add back the values to the map (without keys) .... The important thing here is this line from the docs *The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa.*

Comment: I think I didn't explained good enough. I try to clear the collection, not the map. I added to the description a piece of code that is in the main.

Comment: That bit of code actually made the problem a lot clearer. However, the answer is still the same: `HashMap#values` doesn't support the `add` method.
Besides that, see if you can figure out what happens here: `Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(1, 1);
  map.put(2, 2);
  map.put(3, 3);  
  Collection<Integer> values = map.values();
  values.clear();
  map.forEach((k,v)-> System.out.println(k + " " + v));`

Answer (score 1):

You can not add an item to the values collection of a map

From java documentation of java.util.HashMap.values() operation:

> Collection java.util.HashMap.values()
>   Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the collection is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. 
>   **It does not support the add or addAll operations.**

Answer (score -1):

The scenario is different in terms of HashMap because in a hashmap we take value key pair so if you need to sort the hash map we can sort it on the basis of key.
Arraylist or List are not in the key value form so your sorting method working out there.

Comment: When you actually start thinking of why the `HashMap#values` collection can't be sorted, you indeed need to consider what is being sorted and how. And then this answer suddenly makes a lot more sense. I would encourage you to rephrase your answer and explain it a bit more.